# Matrix factorization and gradient descent for recommender systems; user bias?

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system, matrix-decomposition, gradient-descent

I've been reading about using Matrix Factorization techniques to do collaborative filtering. A popular thing to do seems to be to add user and item biases into the ratings prediction. What I don't understand is why, in some papers (like Factorization meets the Neighbourhood, Koren, Y., 2008), these parameters are learnt. Shouldn't the biases be static whilst training the model? They show tendencies in the actual ratings, right?

Thanks!

Comment: if we add biases in the model, the converge will be faster.